# How can I get errors of serperated function in async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Snippet loading modules:

```
// Initialize Modules
async.series([
    function startServer(callback){
        server(callback);
    },function startScanningBLE(callback){
      noble.on('stateChange', function(state) {
        if (state === 'poweredOn') {
          noble.startScanning([], true);
          console.log("Started scanning");
        } else {
          noble.stopScanning();
        }
      });
    }],
    function(err) {
      if (err) {
        logger.error('[APP] initialization failed', err);
      } else {
        logger.info('[APP] Initialized SUCCESSFULLY');
      }
    }
);
```

I'm not recieving any error. But what I want is to get the errors of startServer() and startScanningBLE(). I tried different ways but for some reason it doesn't wanna join any of the 2 loggers in the error function.

Comment: put the body of each of the two functions in a try catch and put a single callback in the catch clause? In the body of the callback, then, you should eventually put a switch case in order to differentiate the incoming errors..

Comment: are you sure async callbacks are getting called?